# How to debug ~/.forward

Tags: email, procmail

How can I debug `~/.forward` file or see errors logged by mail agent on it **without root privileges**?

I'm trying to process my mail with procmail.

When I invoke procmail manually with

```
procmail < testMailFile
```

it works as expected (my procmail rule logs input to a file).

When no ~/.forward file is present all mail goes to my default mailbox /var/mail/$USER and ~/.procmailrc **is not processed**.

When I create ~/.forward with:

```
"|exec /usr/bin/procmail || exit 75"
```

mail stops coming but `.procmailrc` **is still not processed**.

```
$ lsb_release -a|grep Desc
Description:    CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
$ rpm -q exim
exim-4.63-10.el5
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to use `.forward` for `procmail` if you setup the transport and router configuration for `exim` to deal with procmail directly.

From the [exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_pipe_transport.html#SECID143):

```
# transport
procmail_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  command = /usr/local/bin/procmail -d $local_part
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  check_string = "From "
  escape_string = ">From "
  umask = 077
  user = $local_part
  group = mail

# router
procmail:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
  transport = procmail_pipe
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Comment: @slm Thx. I assume you did the honors of the push

Comment: Yeah I'd been watching your march to it. Saw you were on the edge and lucked out with the honors. I happened to be looking last night at the review queue totals and how you pretty much own them now 8-) so knew you were close.

Comment: Do you imply that these settings can be changed on per-user basis? In original post I mention that procmail is not invoked with or without .forward configuration, meaning my system is probably not configured in this way.

Comment: @Basilevs I was assuming that exim (like postfix that I am using) is configured on a system wide level, but that the individual delivery is dependent on the existence of a users' `~/.procmailrc`.

Comment: -1 as this answers a different question

Answer (score 0):

You may have a few options, but they are not universal.

If the mail server's logs are world-readable, you can examine them for error messages.  If your mail server is `exim`, look for `/var/log/exim/` or perhaps simply `/var/log/mail`.  What exactly gets logged where exactly is ultimately a separate can of worms, where a starting point is the `syslog` configuration, but it's not the only game in town; but if you have `/etc/syslog.conf` on your system, that's probably it (especially if you are on a legacy platform like CentOS).

(If the logs are not world-readable, maybe you can persuade your system administrator to change that, and/or add you to a group which does have read access; or at the very least, grep for error messages related to your `.forward` problem around a particular point in recent time.)

Secondly, do you get a bounce message?  Typically, when the mail server cannot deliver your message, it will send back an error message (DSN, "bounce", "boomerang") with more or less detailed diagnostics.

If you are lucky, you can get a diagnostic without sending yourself email, by connecting to the mail server and talking to it.  Assuming you have an SMTP server running on port 25 on `localhost`, something like

```
bash@centos$ telnet localhost 25
>>> Connecting to localhost ...
>>> 220 Exim is listening, congratulations.
<<< vrfy you@example.com
>>> 454 4.7.1 you@example.com relay access denied
<<< quit
>>> 221 So long, sayonara, au revoir.
```

where `<<<` indicates stuff you type, and `>>>` are the responses from the remote system.  This particular error message is an unlikely outcome, but at least exemplifies what you can expect to see and need to understand (basically, 2xx is okay and 4xx or 5xx is an error, just like in HTTP).

All things counted, Procmail has a fairly limited number of failure modes.  I would suspect permissions on your `.procmailrc` file as the first thing to investigate.

Shameless plug: See also http://porkmail.org/era/mail/procmail-debug.html